# How to setup an email address for sending only?

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, server, amazon-ses, amazon-workmail

My main goal is to setup an email address for my server to use for sending emails only.

I did some research, and it looked like Amazon Simple Email Server and/or Amazon Workmail could provide me with what I needed. I've gotten as far as setting up SES and Workmail so that I can set my server to be able to send emails. However, I saw that once the Workmail inbox is full (50GB), the account would be unable to send emails. Given that this is going to be used by the server and not a human, I didn't want the inbox to get filled with auto replies, spam, or failed to send messages, and then be unable to send emails. So, I went looking for a way to either:

A) prevent emails from being received and stored in the inbox

B) a rule I could setup to delete anything that didn't match the company domain

C) be able to read the inbox and delete email messages using the AWS CLI, and I'd setup my own script to manage how and what was deleted when

So far I haven't had any luck.

Again, I'm not particular how I achieve the goal, but I do preferably need to find a way to have an email address for a server to use exclusively for sending messages. I worry that if I leave it to employees to remember to login and clear the inbox, someone will forget, and then the server will stop sending emails.

Any direction or advice would be greatly appreciated.

I'm not well versed in email protocols; could I setup the address to return a bounce back always, and that would prevent it from receiving emails into it's inbox?

Answer (score 1):

How are you generating these emails? If you are generating them programmatically (via an app/script), you may not need to set up a server. If you just route the outgoing mail through your app to SNS, the emails will be valid, however, there will be no "inbox" for incoming mail and they will just be dumped. This way you don't have to actually worry about an inbox getting full as it will just drop anything coming in.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email.html

In order to receive emails though SNS, you have to go through the setup linked above, but if you do not set this up, then emails will just bounce. At least, that is how I have been doing it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll look into it and see if I can make it work. 

The main purpose I believe will be for emailing password resets, and I was asked to provide SMTP credentials so they could be plugged into environment variables.

Comment: 1+ for the reply, but it doesn't look like AWS SNS is the answer I need, since it uses topics/publishers/subscribers model; I'd have to create a password reset topic for each user, and make sure they were the one and only one ever subscribed to receive password resets for their account.